# How the bottom div takes the rest

Tags: css, layout

Is there a way to do the following layout without using javascript?

```
div parent
   div A
   div B
   div C
```

- **parent** is using a fixed height (say 500px)
- **A** and **B** are growing in height depending on its content
- **C** takes the remaining height
- **C** will get large content which should to be scrolled only within **C**

C will contain a D with large content. D should be scrolled within C

```
   div C
       div D
         large content
```

Comment: Are the divs vertically aligned (stacked) or horizontal (side by side)?

Comment: Is something along these lines what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/N3HPJ/ Note, what possibly may want (the last element stretches to be the full height) can't be done with CSS only, as CSS doesn't do calculated values very well in dynamic, multi-element situations. But you can fake it.

Comment: Or: http://jsfiddle.net/N3HPJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would set it up like so:

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="C">

        <div class="A">
         A's content
        </div>

        <div class="B">
         B's content
        </div> 

      C's content

    </div>/*C end*/

</div>/*parent end*/
```

Comment: I see element nesting. I don't see an answer.

Comment: This layout restructuring will not work since C will get large content to be scrolled

Comment: Add the part about C needing to scroll to your question.